Python 3.10 Windows, failed to install ssh due to bug with installation of pycrypto
Found here that pycrypto is too old package, but it is still requred for ssh module.
can't install pycrypto, python 3.10, how to fix?
pycryptodome gets installed fine for me but still ssh can't work with it, it needs pycrypto.
The trouble is- I have first downloaded the ssh package with all dependencies (pip download ssh)
Then I want to install it (pip install --no-index --find-links . ssh)
I must not just pip install ssh because I am planning to take all the module files with me to another conputer without Internet and install the package.
